# The method getAttribute("value") is not working for textbox

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am new to selenium. I am trying to retrieve the value of a textbox. Below is my code.

```
    WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.id("id"));
    e.sendKeys("text");
    String str = e.getAttribute("value");
    System.out.println(str);
```

The above code is working fine in all sites but is not working for a particular site. I can't  share the site details.

Any explanation regarding why the code is not working for a site or is there another way to get the text from a textbox?

Comment: Can u provide the html of element **e** after entering **text**? Is there an **attribute** **value** in it?

Comment: This is the html after entering text    <input type="text" name="company" placeholder="Firma Name" id="company" class="form-control">.There is no "value" attribute

Comment: Make sure that your text box has value already when you are fetching.

Comment: That's exactly what i am doing but the method is not working for the site i am working

Comment: Please do one thing. Enter the text in the textfield **MANUALLY** Then inspect the textfield with firebug. Then, **paste the html snippet of the textfield here.**

Comment: well that's what i have done when Vivek Singh asked me to provide the html of the element.

Comment: I tried your code using the id "company" and it worked for me

Comment: I din't give the site details then what did u try and for which site did u try

Comment: @RachelD'cruz If the element does not have a `value` attribute then you cannot use the `.getAttribute("value")` method on it. After entering your text, does the element have a `text` component? Have you tried `.getText()` instead?

Answer (score 0):

**getAttribute('value')** will provide you with null cause html snippet doesnot contains **value attribute** or the DOM object of that element has no **value** attribute. Try getting the text with :

```
String str = e.getText(); //If it helps
```

OR
use **JavascriptExecutor** as

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String str = js.executeScript(
                "return document.getElementById('company').value")
                .toString();
```

Comment: Not entirely sure, perhaps it's the JS in your answer that annoyed someone?

Comment: i don;t think so it's bcoz of no value attribute.In gmail also for email and pwd feilds also doesn't have value attribute .i have tried to get those text box values using the getAttribute('value') method it worked fine

Comment: Ah my mistake...i forgot to mention that getAttribute will look also in the dom attached to that particular element. In DOM everything is in a pair of attribute and value. So the case in gmail. Thanks.